# What is happening in these panels of V for Vendetta?

Tags: v-for-vendetta

At the end of *V for Vendetta*, [Evey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evey_Hammond) (disguised as V)

> [rescues] Detective Sergeant Dominic Stone from an angry mob, she brings him to the Shadow Gallery; thus, the cycle begins anew.

These are the panels showing it.

[image: Panels at the end of V for Vendetta]

I'm not sure what's happening here, though. The first two panels seem to show Dominic Stone stumbling in a street, and being dragged into an alley. The next two panels seem to show the same man, a few stories high, and the mob chasing him. The mob turns into the alley, but don't find Dominic, and continue moving along the street. Dominic then passes out looking at Evey.

I don't follow how Evey, carrying a somewhat heavier man, just climbed to the top of a building this easily. Am I misinterpreting the panels? The perspective is a bit askew, so it's a possibility. Otherwise, should I just assume they climbed some fire escape before the mob came around?

Comment: A) We don't know how much time passes between panel 2 and 3  - maybe enough for Evey to help Dominic up a fire escape (he isn't entirely unconscious) .B) There might have been an elevator in the building.. C) Evey may have had a powered grappling hook to pull her up.